# Get data by CheckoutUserId in search rest call

Tags: rest, search-results, crawled-property

I want to get data by CheckoutUserId field in search rest call. I want to filter data from Documents library which are checked out by current user.

```
https://xxx/sites/xxx/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Filename%3C%3E%22AllItems.aspx%22+site:%22https://xxx/sites/xxx/Documents%22%27&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties=%27Title,ModifiedOWSDATE,ListItemID,DefaultEncodingURL,Filename,Created,CheckoutUserOWSUSER%27&sortlist=%27LastModifiedTime:descending%27&startrow=0&rowlimit=11
```

How to get data by CheckoutUserId field.

Comment: Search does not index checked-out versions of files, hence this is a non-working approach

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the files have been checked in before. It may be that you cannot see files that are checked out because the files have never been checked in. Once the initial check in has happened, it becomes visible to all users, even if it's subsequently checked out.

Comment: Yes, all the documents are checked in and after that I have checked out some of them